# getNFTs() of Moralis SDK returning bad request

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp, nft, web3-providers

I am trying to retrieve nfts of an address for a side project.

This is my code.

```
const moralisWeb3 = useMoralisWeb3Api();

  async function connectorValue() {
    try {
      const nfts = await moralisWeb3.account.getNFTs({
        chain: "eth",
        address: account,
      });
      console.log(nfts);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

connectorValue();
```

I am getting a bad request. Am I missing anything. I have already initialized Moralis with app Id and server url.

This is my request object.

```
address: "xxxxxxxx"
chain: "eth"
_ApplicationId: "xxxxxxxx"
_ClientVersion: "js0.0.37"
_InstallationId: "xxxxxxxxx"
```

This is the response.

```
code: 141
error: "[object Object]"
```

Would really appreciate the help in getting this resolved.